# How to remove Wordpress' Jetpack plugin completely?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I had Wordpress' Jetpack installed but I want to completely remove it from my page. I deactivated the plugin and clicked on Delete in the WP Dashboard.

The files are deleted now, but in the database wp_options I can still find values for option names:

```
_transient_timeout_jetpack_https_test
_transient_jetpack_https_test
jetpack_file_data
jetpack_available_modules
jetpack_log
```

So my question is, if I delete the above mentioned Options is Jetpack than completely removed or do i have to do other steps? I can not find any resource which teaches about removing Jetpack completely and clean...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can typically check the plugin's source for actions it performs on uninstall (if any). In case of Jetpack its [`uninstall.php`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/jetpack/trunk/uninstall.php) does remove some options, but none of those you mention.

It is hard to say what would *complete* removal be, without making thorough audit of before and after states of the system. It's pretty typical for long running WP install to have leftover options in practice.